# How to show that the following metric space is totally bounded?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d_1)$ and $(X,d_2)$ be compact metric spaces. Furthermore, let $X = X_1 \times X_2$, and define $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}, ((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)) \mapsto \max(d_1(x_1,y_1), d_2(x_2,y_2)) $.

I want to prove that $(X,d)$ is compact. I'm trying to show this by proving that $(X,d)$ is both complete and totally bounded. I already showed that $(X,d)$ is complete, but I have some difficulties showing that $(X,d)$ is totally bounded.

Question: can you (help me) show that $(X,d)$ is totally bounded, given the information above?

To be clear: we consider $X$ to be totally bounded, if for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exist some $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n \in X$ with $ X = B_{ \epsilon } (x_1) \cup \dots \cup B_{ \epsilon } (x_n) $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are totally bounded, so there exist $x_1,...,x_n \in X_1$ and $y_1,...,y_m \in X_2$ such that $X_1= \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\epsilon)$ and $X_2= \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m B(y_i,\epsilon)$. Now, you can show that $X= \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^m B((x_i,y_j),\epsilon)$.

Comment: But how do we show this? It seems obvious, but it isn't entirely clear to me how to prove it.

Comment: @Max: Suppose that $\langle x,y\rangle\in X_1\times X_2$. There is an $i$ such that $x\in B(x_i,\epsilon)$, and there is a $j$ such that $y\in B(y_j,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott aha... thanks.

Comment: @Max: You’re welcome.